# Can I embed a windows app installer in my app for automatic updates if I intend to sell the app both on the store and my own website?

Tags: windows-app-sdk

I am developing a desktop application for windows and I want to sell it on the windows store but also on my own website. I want automatic updates and I see that I can include an embedded app installer in my project to accomplish that ([directions on this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/how-to-embed-an-appinstaller-file?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=hL3Qp0zRBOc&ranSiteID=hL3Qp0zRBOc-faURvpCBNpARFuFN5G9_sQ&epi=hL3Qp0zRBOc-faURvpCBNpARFuFN5G9_sQ&irgwc=1&OCID=AIDcmm549zy227_aff_7593_1243925&tduid=(ir__ldd6hsn30okfdlbfrwbsc66or32x9usitppyy03u00)(7593)(1243925)(hL3Qp0zRBOc-faURvpCBNpARFuFN5G9_sQ)())). I'm not sure if I can host the app on the windows store with that installer embedded or if I need to have two different versions of the app; one with an embedded installer for automatic updates that I host on my website and another that just allows the windows store to handle updates? Thnx ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two different versions of the app: one with an embedded installer for automatic updates that you host on your website and another that allows the windows store to handle updates.